being developed or under development application?
Please help me formulate this sentence correctly:

Security audit of being developed (or under development?)  and deployed applications

By this I mean security audits that are conducted for applications that are in the develompent phase (still being developed) and already deployed applications.

I can't provide an authoritative reference, thus comment instead of Answer, but in my experience the formulation would be ...security audit of applications under development and deployed applications.

Yes it seems very odd to use "being developed" as a premodifier for a noun, even without "and deployed". So putting "under development" before the noun isn't any better.

Security audit of applications deployed or under development would be a noun phrase that could be used as the title of a report providing info on the known-risk status of applications already in use and those still under development.
We tend not to use participial phrases and prepositional phrases in front of the nouns they modify:

*being developed applications no
*under development applications no

but afterwards:

applications being developed yes
applications under development yes

